# Vibration after regular intervals

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a beep system which gives you four beeps. One beep after a second for one second.

However If its silent mode i want the vibrator to do the same, vibrate for 1 second 4 times after 1 second.

This is the code I am using

```
 long[] pattern = new long[2];
                    pattern[0] = 10;
                    pattern [1] = 30;
                      switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
                      {

                      case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                          vibe.vibrate(pattern, 0);
                          break;
                      case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                          soundsOn(mp);
                          break;
```

Kindly how can i do what i want to do

Best Regards

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What is your problem exactly?

Comment: it vibrates for a very long time no steps no intervals etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move your `pattern` into your vibrate case and this my interpretation of "vibrate for 1 second 4 times after 1 second.":

```
switch (am.getRingerMode())  {
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
    long[] pattern = new long[8];
    pattern[0] = 1000; // Wait one second
    pattern[1] = 950;  // Vibrate for most a second
    pattern[2] = 50;   // A pause long enough to feel distinction
    pattern[3] = 950;  // Repeat 3 more times
    pattern[4] = 50;
    pattern[5] = 950;
    pattern[6] = 50;
    pattern[7] = 950;
    vibe.vibrate(pattern, -1);
    break;
case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
    soundsOn(mp);
    break;
}
```